# kubeadm config images pull fails

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am trying to install k8s on a new machine running Ubuntu 20.04 using containerd and kubeadm is failing to load the images:

`# kubeadm config images pull --kubernetes-version=1.21.0 --image-repository registry.k8s.io`

failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.21.0": output: time="2023-06-14T15:24:34Z" level=fatal msg="validate service connection: CRI v1 image API is not implemented for endpoint "unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock": rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1.ImageService"
, error: exit status 1

I checked containerd and it is running.

```
# systemctl status containerd
● containerd.service - containerd container runtime
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/containerd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-06-14 15:21:35 UTC; 9min ago
```

I don't have /etc/containerd/config.toml so it is using default configuration.

The plugins list is exactly the same as another (much older) working machine:

```
# ctr plugins list
TYPE                            ID                       PLATFORMS      STATUS
io.containerd.content.v1        content                  -              ok
io.containerd.snapshotter.v1    aufs                     linux/amd64    ok
io.containerd.snapshotter.v1    btrfs                    linux/amd64    skip
io.containerd.snapshotter.v1    devmapper                linux/amd64    error
io.containerd.snapshotter.v1    native                   linux/amd64    ok
io.containerd.snapshotter.v1    overlayfs                linux/amd64    ok
io.containerd.snapshotter.v1    zfs                      linux/amd64    skip
io.containerd.metadata.v1       bolt                     -              ok
io.containerd.differ.v1         walking                  linux/amd64    ok
io.containerd.gc.v1             scheduler                -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        introspection-service    -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        containers-service       -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        content-service          -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        diff-service             -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        images-service           -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        leases-service           -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        namespaces-service       -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        snapshots-service        -              ok
io.containerd.runtime.v1        linux                    linux/amd64    ok
io.containerd.runtime.v2        task                     linux/amd64    ok
io.containerd.monitor.v1        cgroups                  linux/amd64    ok
io.containerd.service.v1        tasks-service            -              ok
io.containerd.internal.v1       restart                  -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           containers               -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           content                  -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           diff                     -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           events                   -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           healthcheck              -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           images                   -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           leases                   -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           namespaces               -              ok
io.containerd.internal.v1       opt                      -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           snapshots                -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           tasks                    -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           version                  -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           cri                      linux/amd64    ok
```

```
# dpkg -s kubeadm | grep Version
Version: 1.21.0-00
```

(kubelet and kubectl are the same)

```
# dpkg -s containerd | grep Version
Version: 1.5.9-0ubuntu1~20.04.6
```

The versions match the other machines already in the cluster.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an issue with the old containerd provided by Ubuntu 20.
You can try the following steps (as root):

1. Set up the Docker repository as described in this [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository)
2. Remove the old containerd: `apt remove containerd`
3. Update repository data and install the new containerd: `apt update, apt install containerd.io`
4. Remove the installed default config file: `rm /etc/containerd/config.toml` (if it exist)
5. Restart containerd: `systemctl restart containerd`

Comment: Thanks. The most recent containerd provided by Ubuntu also works. I was trying to use a version close to the other machines already in the cluster.